# Testing java web start application using jemmy

Tags: java, java-web-start, jemmy

I need to create some gui tests using Jemmy but I have no idea how to launch it with javaws application. 
In tutorials/examples/etc is something like that:

```
new ClassReference("org.netbeans.jemmy.explorer.GUIBrowser")
                                                        .startApplication();
```

This code opens an example window, but how can I, using ClassReference object open `*.jnlp` file? Or **is it another way to "connect" jemmy with java web start application?**

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by preparing special build with Jemmy included and call Jemmy from the app run in jnlp mode itself.

Comment: Could you please provide a little bit more information about this solution: "special build with Jemmy included" - do i need to do any coding in AUT or just need to add jemmy.jar to build path; "call Jemmy from the app run in jnlp mode" - what do you mean by this, any code examples?

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko, I meant bundling jemmy.jar with your application. Not only on build phase, but on deploy as well. It's an easiest way to overcome the security complexities of the web start. After that you can call Jemmy whatever way you want from your code.

Comment: "After that you can call Jemmy whatever way you want from your code" you mean call Jemmy from code of Application Under Test?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

1. Place build files into any folder on your PC.
2. Add `.jar` files from this build to your testing project.
3. Open `.jnlp` file in text editor and search for main application class

   `application-desc main-class="[Main application class]"/>`
4. Call it from you test to launch app

   `new ClassReference("[Main application class]").startApplication();`

Now you can access elements of this Java app from test environment

Answer (score 1):

### [You can use Jemmy with JUnit in NetBeans IDE.](https://dzone.com/articles/how-use-jemmy-junit-netbeans)

For the GUI testing we are using Jemmy, a library that comes with the NetBeans IDE and is very useful for testing Swing applications.

JUnit tests that utilize Jemmy so for example:

```
@Test
public void JunitTest() {
JFrameOperator mainFrame = new JFrameOperator();
JTextFieldOperator textField = new JTextFieldOperator(mainFrame, "textIn");
int x = 10;
assertEquals(x, textField.getLocationOnScreen().x);
}
```

Adding the `@Test` annotation and making use of JUnit's `assertEquals()` and `fail()` if needed.

---

### Another Approach:

You can also do it using jnlp. Already suggested @[Sergey Grinev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1054140/sergey-grinev)

### [A good example and running code is given in this link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681949/how-to-automate-a-swing-java-web-start-application-which-runs-clicking-a-link-in)

**Snapshot:**

1. Click the jnlp file link in webdriver, save jnlp file to disk;
2. Run the webstart app from jnlp;
3. Capture opened app and use it for test.

### This process can be done by using following libraries:

- [netx](http://jnlp.sourceforge.net/netx/) - for running webstart application from jnlp.
- [uispec4j](http://www.uispec4j.org/) - for intercepting created webstart window and
  manipulating window elements.

You can probably do the same trick with other AWT/Swing testing tool, but uispec4j allows to intercept webstart app executed from jnlp, you don't need to run the app by calling main() and you don't need to have your webstart app source code in your testing code repo.

Credit goes to [tporeba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3484881/tporeba)

For learning more about Jemmy, you can go through this link

1. [Jemmy Tutorial](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Jemmy_Tutorial#Using_the_Event_queue)
2. [Jemmy Samples](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Jemmy_Samples)
3. [NetBeans Platform Test Infrastructure Tutorial](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-test.html)

Comment: Thanks, what about your explanation about usage of Jemmy with web-start app? Yes/No? Why?