# Launching .exe with Jemmy

Tags: java, automation, awt, jemmy

I am new to Jemmy. The first thing I am struggling is launching my Installer.exe file. I have googled around and couldn't find answers. I need a basic steps to launch the app and hook with it so that I can interact with AWT controls on the dialogs of the installer.

The only relevent thing is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630117/testing-java-web-start-application-using-jemmy). But I am not knowledgeable about .jnlp. I am not sure how can I find *[Main application class]*  from my Installer.exe

Comment: what "Installer.exe" file?

Comment: It is basically an installer of our product, that we have and we want to automate that installer.

Comment: and .. what has any of that got to do with the Jemmy library?

Comment: I want to automate the this GUI installer using Jemmy.

Comment: the purpose of Jemmy is to create automated tests. Your task doesn't seem to have anything to do with tests.

Comment: I want to create automated tests for my installer. For that purpose I want to launch the Installer.exe using jemmy. How Can I do that?

Comment: "automated tests for my installer" .... how is that supposed to make any sense?

Comment: I have an Windows installer for my product. When I run the installer it moves me through different dialogs, where I have to select different settings on different dialogs. I have to test the installer by selecting different options on each dialog page. So I want to automate the testing of the installer's installation process. For that purpose I want use the Jemmy.
I hope that clarifies.

Comment: I know what you are trying to do, it just makes no sense. That "windows installer", is that part of your Java project (meaning, did you write it in Java) ?

Comment: Yes, that is written in Java. It has AWT controls which I want to interact with.

Comment: AWT? When was it written? 2000? Nobody bothered to test it then?

Comment: Swing components actually.

Comment: @TanzeelUrRahman Have u solved it yet? I meet the same problem.

Comment: @David no I couldn't.  So apparently you can only use it if your automation code and Jemmy library is part of your actual applicationunder test. There is a paid tool called Squish. You can give it a try that is best to interact with Java's awt/swt controls.