# UISpec4j for JNLP - Make window visible

Tags: java, testing, automation, jnlp, uispec4j

I am trying to use UISpec4j and NetX to test JNLP. Got the solution from [How to automate a swing java web start application which runs clicking a link into a web application, which is automated with Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681949/how-to-automate-a-swing-java-web-start-application-which-runs-clicking-a-link-in)

But I need to make the JNLP app visible. Is it possible to do that in UISpec4j?

Comment: Why is the app. invisible? Sounds nefarious to me..

Comment: UISpec4j makes the app invisible. I need to make it visible for us to write the test scripts.